# SparkSQL function require type Decimal

Tags: scala, types, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I designed the following function to work with arrays of any numeric type:

```
def array_sum[T](item:Traversable[T])(implicit n:Numeric[T]) = item.sum
// Registers a function as a UDF so it can be used in SQL statements.
sqlContext.udf.register("array_sumD", array_sum(_:Seq[Float]))
```

But wanting to pass an array of type float me the following error:

```
// Now we can use our function directly in SparkSQL.
sqlContext.sql("SELECT array_sumD(array(5.0,1.0,2.0)) as array_sum").show
```

Error:

```
 cannot resolve 'UDF(array(5.0,1.0,2.0))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<double> type, however, 'array(5.0,1.0,2.0)' is of array<decimal(2,1)> type;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default data type for decimal values in Spark-SQL is, well, decimal. If you **cast** your literals in the query into floats, and use the same UDF, it works:

```
sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT array_sumD(array(
    |  CAST(5.0 AS FLOAT),
    |  CAST(1.0 AS FLOAT),
    |  CAST(2.0 AS FLOAT)
    |)) as array_sum""".stripMargin).show
```

The result, as expected:

```
+---------+
|array_sum|
+---------+
|      8.0|
+---------+
```

**Alternatively**, if you *do* want to use decimals (to avoid floating point issues), you'll *still* have to use casting to get the right *precision*, plus you won't be able to use Scala's nice `Numeric` and `sum`, as decimals are read as `java.math.BigDecimal`. So - your code would be:

```
def array_sum(item:Traversable[java.math.BigDecimal]) = item.reduce((a, b) => a.add(b))

// Registers a function as a UDF so it can be used in SQL statements.
sqlContext.udf.register("array_sumD", array_sum(_:Seq[java.math.BigDecimal]))

sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT array_sumD(array(
    |  CAST(5.0 AS DECIMAL(38,18)),
    |  CAST(1.0 AS DECIMAL(38,18)),
    |  CAST(2.0 AS DECIMAL(38,18))
    |)) as array_sum""".stripMargin).show
```